# Hibernate multiple @ManyToMany associations to the same entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following scenario:

I have an entity called `MyOtherEntity` that has a type attribute.
`MyEntity` is associated only with certain `MyOtherEntity` entities based on the type of `MyOtherEntity`.

`MyEntity` class (only for demonstration it's not modelled correctly):

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "my_entity_my_other_entity_type1",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "my_other_entity_id")}
    )
    private List<MyOtherEntity> myOtherEntityType1;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "my_entity_my_other_entity_type2",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "my_other_entity_id")}
    )
    private List<MyOtherEntity> myOtherEntityType2;

    // more fields
}
```

`MyOtherEntity` class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_other_entity")
public class MyOtherEntity {

    private String type;

    // more fields
}
```

A more detailed example:

Let's say there are only 3 types of `MyOtherEntity` type1, type2, and type3. My goal is to only associate `MyEntity` with `MyOtherEntity` entities of type1 and type2.

Is this functionality possible to achieve using Hibernate?

Comment: Join your MyOtherEntity  only one time.

Comment: this way when I fetch `MyEntity` all `MyOtherEntity` entities will also be fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @Where annotation.

```
@Where(clause = "type = 'tyep1'")
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "my_entity_my_other_entity_type1",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "my_other_entity_id")}
)
private List<MyOtherEntity> myOtherEntityType1;

@Where(clause = "type = 'tyep2'")
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "my_entity_my_other_entity_type2",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "my_other_entity_id")}
)
private List<MyOtherEntity> myOtherEntityType2;
```

Comment: This will work but I think it will be extremely slow if you consider that I will have over 100 types and multiple rows.